# Or And syntax (||; &&) with two arguments

Tags: ruby

I am writing this code to check if a number is even and divisible by 7. The objective is to make use of "&&" or "||". Since I want both even number and divisible by 7, it will be "&&".This is my code.

```
input = gets.to_i
def divisible_by_seven?(input)

    div_by_seven = input % 7
    is_even = is_even?(input)

    if div_by_seven == 0 && is_even == true 
        return "is divisible by 7 and is even"

    elsif div_by_seven == 0 && is_even == false
        return "is divisible by 7 but is not even"

    elsif div_by_seven != 0 && is_even == true
        return "is not divisible by 7 but is even"

    else
        return "is not divisible by 7 and is not even"
    end    
end

puts "#{input} #{is_even_and_divisible_by_seven?(input)}"
```

Is there a way to better write this?

Comment: Is "is divisible by 5" on line 8 supposed to be "is divisible by 7"?

Comment: What is `is_even_and_divisible_by_seven?`? What is `is_even?`?

Comment: A quick improvement would be to replace `is_even == true` with `is_even` and `is_even == false` with `!is_even`.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is.

```
def is_even_and_divisible_by_seven?(input)
  case [(input % 7).zero?, input.even?]
  when [true, true] then "is divisible by 7 and is even"
  when [true, false] then "is divisible by 7 but is not even"
  when [false, true] then "is not divisible by 7 but is even"
  when [false, false] then "is not divisible by 7 and is not even"
end

input = gets.to_i
puts "#{input} #{is_even_and_divisible_by_seven?(input)}"
```

or

```
def is_even_and_divisible_by_seven?(input)
  [(input % 7).zero?, input.even?]
end

input = gets.to_i
x, y = is_even_and_divisible_by_seven?(input)
puts "#{input} is#{" not" unless x} divisible by 7 "\
     "#{x == y ? "and" : "but"} is#{" not" unless y} even"
```

Comment: Thanks @sawa but I am working to make the code use && operation

Comment: That is not in the question.

Comment: `&&` can't be overridden because it's not a method. Neither can `||`.

Comment: Hello @sawa. This works (but does not make use of && - I have both && I I in the title and in my solution. I can specify that in the original request too) def is_even_and_divisible_by_seven?(input)
  [(input % 7).zero?, input.even?]
end

input = gets.to_i
x, y = is_even_and_divisible_by_seven?(input)
puts "#{input} is#{" not" unless x} divisible by 7 "\
     "#{x == y ? "and" : "but"} is#{" not" unless y} even"

Answer (score 0):

A quick improvement would be to replace `div_by_seven = input % 7` with `div_by_seven = input % 7 == 0`. Also, replace `is_even == true` with `is_even`, or just `input.even?`, and `is_even == false` with `!input.even?`.

```
def divisible_by_seven_and_even?(input)
  div_by_seven = input % 7 == 0

  if div_by_seven && input.even?
    "is divisible by 7 and is even"
  elsif div_by_seven && !input.even?
    "is divisible by 7 but is not even"
  elsif !div_by_seven && input.even?
    "is not divisible by 7 but is even"
  else
    "is not divisible by 7 and is not even"
  end    
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If an integer is even (divided by 2) and is divided by 7, then it's divided by 14.